# Inverse Square Root Of Matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics

So let's say a matrix is A. Then how do you find `A^-1/2`? It seems to be different from finding the inverse of A. Could someone provide a simple example as explanation? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Compute the square root, then take the inverse of the square root.

Answer (score 3):

We assume that $A$ is hermitian $> 0$. Using Cholesky, $A=R^*R$. Using the polar decomposition of $R^{-1}$, $R^{-1}=HU$, where $U$ is unitary and $H$ is hermitian $>0$. Then $A^{1/2}=UR,A^{-1/2}=R^{-1}U^*$.

Proof. $UR=H^{-1}R^{-1}R=H^{-1}$ is hermitian $>0$.

$A=R^*R=H^{-1}UU^*H^{-1}=(H^{-1})^2$.

Remark. This method is interesting, because there is a very fast and stable iterative algorithm calculating an approximation of $U$ (cf. polar-Newton algorithm in Functions of Matrices, Higham).

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the square root of a matrix M using the Cholesky Decomposition, M = LL'. Then compute the inverse of L